# How to create a folder and ask the user where to save it to in C#?

Tags: c#, save, directory

I think that all i need is in the question. I placed my method in my Form.Load I can either create a folder or open a SaveFileDialog but not both at once.

If someone could help me please.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you not create a folder in the explorer window that `SaveFileDialog` uses? Right click -> New Folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SaveFileDialog lets the user choose a file location that *already exists*.  If not, they can create a folder within the dialog as @Bali suggested.

If you want the user to be able to create a new folder without using the dialog then you'll need to let the user type the path (e.g. in a textbox). Then you can check to see if the directory exist using `Directory.Exist`, and if not, create it using `Directory.Create`.

```
void CheckPath(string path)
{
   var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
   if( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dir) && !Directory.Exists(dir))
      Directory.Create(dir);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open a [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) for the user with the title ([`Description`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.description.aspx) property) set to something like "Choose an existing folder or create a new one". Do not forget to set its [`ShowNewFolderButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.shownewfolderbutton.aspx) property to true.

You can also use the `FolderBrowserDialog` to ask the user only to select the containing ("parent") folder, and create the new folder yourself by calling [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx). In this case, `ShowNewFolderButton` should be false.

Answer (score 0):

This would be to create a new directory

```
 Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Your File Path Here");
```

This would be to open a file. You can select where it opens the initial directory of the file by changing the path.

```
 OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = (@"C:\Your starting File Path");
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a File";
```